# Wygwam - adding link cannot close window

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

EE 2.7.3
WYGWAM 3.2.2

When using Internet Explorer I try to add a link using WYGWAM and after I enter the URL i click OK and the pop up window will not close.  Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

We [just released](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/wygwam-3.3) Wygwam 3.3 which fixes compatibility issues with Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug with ckeditor upon which WYGWAM is built. Pixel and Tonic have said fix is coming soon in new release of WYGWAM.